# Migrating from Picasa to Googleapis

Tags: php, google-signin

I want to migrate my below php code from Picasa to Googleapis for my Google-login in my website, so I can get the user thumbnail image.

Can someone please help me convert the below code to GoogleAPI, as picasa API has been deprecated.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/'.$user['google_id'].'?alt=json');
$d = json_decode($data);
$avatar = $d->{'entry'}->{'gphoto$thumbnail'}->{'$t'};
```